# Automatic transition between multiple divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, transition, banner

Still can't seem to get the hang of it. I'm trying to create a smooth transition between multiple `div`s with a background image. The transition is working but it is far from smooth. Please advise.

```js
var divs = jQuery('.image');

function fade() {
    var current = jQuery('.current');
    var currentIndex = divs.index(current),
        nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;

    if (nextIndex >= divs.length) {
        nextIndex = 0;
    }

    var next = divs.eq(nextIndex);

    next.stop().animate({'opacity': 1}, 2500).addClass('current');

    current.stop().animate({'opacity': 0}, 2500).removeClass('current');
        setTimeout(fade, 2500);
    };

fade();
```

```css
.image {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top:0;
      display:none;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position:top;
    }
    .banner {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    }
.current {display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner">
    <div id="image-0" class="image current" style="background-image:url(http://doetinpop.wildscreen.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/popkoor-32.jpg);"></div>
  <div id="image-1" class="image" style="background-image:url(http://doetinpop.wildscreen.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/MG_6884.jpg);"></div>
  <div id="image-2" class="image" style="background-image:url(http://doetinpop.wildscreen.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/MG_6893.jpg);"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not related to php as far as I can see. You should probably remove the tag and show the html instead of the php that generates it. And perhaps the css.

Comment: Thanks, Edited the post.

Comment: I don't have an example ready, but if you use different z-indices you only need to transition the top one and modify the z-indices after the transition has finished. That should make it smoother already.

Comment: Still can't get it working. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is currently happening / what is your desired effect?

Comment: I've edited your snippet to include jQuery so that it would run. However, given that your background images are resulting in 404 is not helping. Consider including images from a service like [lorem pixel](http://lorempixel.com/).